# Why was my macOS login password reset for the second time without my intention?

Tags: macos, mojave, password, filevault

Today, for the second time in a 2-yearly span it happened to me that my macOS login password stopped being accepted overnight and I had to reset it via Apple Id (it doesn't let you use anything but alphanumerical though - t says the password change was successful but the password is not accepted). Has anyone else had this issue  recently?

For the recent incident OS version was 10.14.4 (18E226), not sure about the previous one (could have been Mojave as well).

FileVault is enabled

It happened around 12:00 so you may see last message before it happened and the first after I wanted to login but was unable to do so.

The hardware is MacBookPro13,3 (15" 2016)

system.log:

```
Apr 27 10:27:26 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[45]: ASL Sender Statistics
Apr 27 10:32:55 MacBook-Pro-Szymon com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501): Service "com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.loginwindow.100" tried to register for endpoint "com.apple.tsm.uiserver" already registered by owner: com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
Apr 27 10:33:24 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr 27 10:33:23 MacBook-Pro-Szymon timed[85]: settimeofday({0x5cc413d3,0xf2e29}) == 0
Apr 27 10:33:30 MacBook-Pro-Szymon timed[85]: settimeofday({0x5cc413da,0xe68a7}) == 0
Apr 27 10:34:33 MacBook-Pro-Szymon com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sandboxd[3206]): Service exited due to SIGALRM | sent by kernel_task[0]
Apr 27 12:14:41 MacBook-Pro-Szymon bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1556360081 0
Apr 27 12:14:54 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[43]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Apr 27 12:14:54 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[43]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Apr 27 12:14:54 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[43]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.family.asl" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Apr 27 12:14:54 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[43]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Apr 27 12:14:54 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[43]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.contacts.ContactsUICore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Apr 27 12:14:54 MacBook-Pro-Szymon syslogd[43]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
```

Comment: I still think it could have been Mojave - period of 1 past year is included in the 2 past years ;) it could have been Mavericks, but somehow it's less likely to me

Comment: yep - my fault - by any chance do you know something about the issue or someone who might know? I think we've had enough discussion about what OS it was...